# Missing pepe coin in trust wallet

Tags: trustwallet

Was my trust wallet hacked? What should I do now?  I didn't approve the following;

Transaction Hash:
0xbc7dca5e7aaa9294993b6387192a31fc7343fdb0f29be95fa14c04ca599b8f54
Status:
Success
Block:
17216163
99 Block Confirmations
Timestamp:
20 mins ago (May-08-2023 01:46:59 PM +UTC)|Confirmed within 30 secs

From:
0xd5b6E0aeaCf4B17FA522E783A0E82029138111E1 (Fake_Phishing139655)
Interacted With (To):
0x6982508145454Ce325dDbE47a25d4ec3d2311933 (Pepe: PEPE Token)
ERC-20 Tokens Transferred:
From
0x704eeD...f418705A
To
Fake_Phishing139655
For
563,877,235.91669508055202346
($1,272.89)

Pepe...
(PEPE...)